# Alternatives for TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1); SpigotMC/ SpigotMC event not running

Tags: java, events, delay, bukkit, timeunit

I was trying to make a Minecraft plugin while having this problem, but I thought this would be more of a Java discussion

So I tried to make a spawner that would spawn a chicken every second (for testing, it would become every minute when I'm done), but while I was testing the event doesn't seem to run (because `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep()` would block the MC thread). So may I have an alternative?
The delay I'm using as for now is `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(*insert some number here*);`
 As shown here: 
 
 Note: I already tried using `setTaskTimer` and `scheduleSyncRepeatingTask` as shown in the answers, but they didn't seem to work. Is this an event issue or a `spawnEntity` issue?

```
package com.TheRealBee.Bows.Event10;


import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.entity.EntityType;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.block.BlockPlaceEvent;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class EventManager10 implements Listener {
        @EventHandler

        public void onNukePlace(BlockPlaceEvent e){


            // Return if it's not TNT, doesn't have ItemMeta or doesn't have a custom dispaly name
            if(!e.getBlock().getType().equals(Material.GOLD_BLOCK) || !e.getItemInHand().hasItemMeta() || !e.getItemInHand().getItemMeta().hasDisplayName())
                return;
            // Return if the item display name is not correct
            if(!e.getItemInHand().getItemMeta().getDisplayName().equals(ChatColor.WHITE+"Spawner"))
                return;
            // Create the explosion
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < 300000000; i++) {
                    e.getBlock().getLocation().getWorld().spawnEntity(e.getBlock().getLocation(), EntityType.CHICKEN);
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                }
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ex)
            {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            
        }
}
```

Comment: You're blocking the minecraft thread for 1 second. Also, 300000000, what?

Comment: [There are Bukkit-specific solutions](https://bukkit.org/threads/solved-adding-a-timer-that-repeats-an-event.36562/), no need to (mis)use standard Java APIs.

Comment: @Jason convert that into an answer for the error and an alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(...)` in place of that for loop and `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep`

```java
Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(plugin, new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        e.getBlock().getLocation().getWorld().spawnEntity(e.getBlock().getLocation(), EntityType.CHICKEN);
    }

}, 0L, 20L)
```

`plugin` should be the instance of your plugin

`0L` is the delay (in ticks) before the first task is run

`20L` is the delay (in ticks) before the next task is run

[scheduleSyncRepeatingTask in the Spigot JavaDoc](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/scheduler/BukkitScheduler.html#scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(org.bukkit.plugin.Plugin,java.lang.Runnable,long,long))

As this is a spawner I assume you will want to stop spawning chickens when the block is broken. You can cancel a task using its taskID. The taskID is the integer that `scheduleSyncRepeatingTask` returns. You should save this taskID because you can cancel the task later (when the block breaks). To cancel the task you can use `cancelTask`:

```java
Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().cancelTask(taskID);
```

[cancelTask in the Spigot JavaDoc](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/scheduler/BukkitScheduler.html#cancelTask(int))

Save this taskID using for example a HashMap. When the block is place you should save the coordinates as key and the taskID as the value in the HashMap. When the block is broken (use the block break event) you should lookup the coordinates of the broken block in that HashMap. If the coordinates exist in the HashMap you should cancel the task and remove the entry from the HashMap.

Comment: Well it still doesn't spawn chickens

Comment: How did you improve on your code? Do you know if the runnable is even being called? Maybe test with a `Bukkit.broadcastMessage(...)` instead of the `spawnEntity` line. Can you update your answer with your new code that is "not spawning chickens"?

Comment: I'll come back to you in about 8 hours (I'm in school and the network disabled minecraft)

Comment: I ment update your question. Can't update the comment for some reason.

Comment: Well I was stupid and when I called the spawner thing it was chatcolor.AQUA your solution is actually correct :P

Comment: How do you use cancelTask and what is the taskID in this case

Answer (score 1):

As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67287699/11916773), you could use a [runnable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html). Bukkit has [baked in methods](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/scheduler/BukkitRunnable.html) to utilise this Java feature. This is preferred as using `Thread.sleep()` (what `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep()` wraps) will pause the main thread in which Minecraft is running; calling that will pause everything (player movement, other plugins, world generation etc) and will cause clients to disconnect if prolonged.

To get the result you're after; a repeating action, you should use the [`runTaskTimer`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/scheduler/BukkitRunnable.html#runTaskTimer(org.bukkit.plugin.Plugin,long,long)) scheduler. There are a few ways to call this scheduler but the easiest by far is like so:

```java
Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskTimer(plugin, () -> e.getBlock().getLocation().getWorld().spawnEntity(e.getBlock().getLocation(), EntityType.CHICKEN), 0L, 100L);
```

Where `plugin` is the instance of your plugin, `() -> ...` is a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) to call the one action we want to execute, `0L` is the delay to start the task (where `L` represents a [long](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html)) and finally `100L` is 5 seconds in ticks. There are 20 ticks per second so you would perform `seconds * 20` to get the ticks you want for the delay (e.g. 60 * 20 = 1200L for 1 minute).

`runTaskTimer` will return an instance of [`BukkitTask`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/scheduler/BukkitTask.html) that you can store and then later [cancel](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/scheduler/BukkitTask.html#cancel()) when you want the chickens to stop spawning.

There are a few ways to get your plugin instance but one way would be to simply pass the instance to the listener when you call it from your main, e.g.:

```java
Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new EventManager10(this), this);
```

And then you would swap out the default [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) for your own in `EventManager10`:

```java
private final JavaPlugin plugin;

public EventManager10(JavaPlugin plugin){
    this.plugin = plugin;
}
```

Generally speaking, `EventManager10` is not in line with [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html), perhaps take a read of those as it will help you as your project expands.

Comment: Okay I get about the Java naming conventions, but when I'm done it said that I would need a expression in the bracket for the lambda expression... I already forgot I have the memory of 0.01 of a gpldfish

Comment: `(parameters) -> {expression}` is valid with empty parameters so if your IDE is giving you a warning, you likely mistyped or your Java version is set to < 8.

Comment: Oh this works too but I'm not sure who came first so I'm assuming the higher one is the one who got it